# One to zero/one relationship with EF6, MySQL, MVC error

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have my entities setup:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual Permissions Permissions { get; set; }
    ... 
}
public class Permissions
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public bool UserType1 { get; set; }
    public bool UserType2 { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The intention is to have a pretty straightforward setup with the permissions separated into another table. When seeding the database, I create some users with the permissions setup correctly (checking the tables with the external editor they have matching keys for the user/permissions entries). The setup code is:

```
public class EfDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<EfDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(EfDbContext context)
    {

        // Add admin user

        User admin = new User
        {
            UserName = "Admin",
            Password = "pass",
            FirstName = "Administrator",
            LastName = "Web",
            Permissions = new Permissions().SetAdminPermissions()
        };
        context.Users.Add(admin);

        context.Users.Add(new User { UserName = "User1", Password = "pass", FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", CreatedBy = admin, Permissions = new Permissions().AddFullPermissions().AddInstructorPermissions() });
        context.Users.Add(new User { UserName = "User2", Password = "pass", FirstName = "Jenny", LastName = "Doh", CreatedBy = admin, Permissions = new Permissions().AddFullPermissions().AddBasicPermissions() });
        context.Users.Add(new User { UserName = "User3", Password = "pass", FirstName = "Sasha", LastName = "Grey", CreatedBy = admin, Permissions = new Permissions().AddBasicPermissions() });
        context.Users.Add(new User { UserName = "User4", Password = "pass", FirstName = "Arnold", LastName = "Schwarzenegger", CreatedBy = admin, Permissions = new Permissions().AddInstructorPermissions() });          
        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

However, when trying to access the corresponding entities I get  exceptions all the time. For example, directly in the controller I have

```
  if (filter == "Type1")
                    return View(_repository.Users.Where(p => p.Permissions.UserType1));
```

Running the corresponding action gives the exception

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException was unhandled by user code
```

I have tried to disable the Lazy Evaluation in the DB configuration (Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; ). The exception then changes to:

```
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Web.WebUI.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Inspecting the "p" object in the lambda I see that the fields are successfully set (Username, password etc.), but the Permissions field is null.

I use MySql.Data 6.9.6; MySql.Data.Entity 6.9.6; EntityFramework 6.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Try _repository.Users.Include(u => u.Permissions).Where(p => p.Permissions.UserType1)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot. For anyone else reading this - I also had to change IEnumerable<User> to IQueryable<User> in EfUserRepository class; also the lazy evaluation had to be disabled.